# how can I upload and parse big files from logstash to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I have a 3 nodes cluster with 1 master and 2 data nodes each is set for 1TB
I have increased both -Xms24g -Xmx24g to half my ram (48GB total)
I than successfully upload 140mb file from Kibana to elk from the GUI after increasing it from 100mb to 1GB
when I tried to upload same file with only logstash the process was stuck and broke elastic
my pipeline is fairly simple

```
input {
file {
path => "/tmp/*_log"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

small files works great. I'm not able to push big files.
log contains 1 million rows
I set all fields in /etc/security/limits.conf to unlimited
any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: You need to set the [`start_position`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-start_position) option to `beginning` in the file input, if you do not set this, logstash will read the files from the end, which means that only new lines will be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to increase memory sizing in /etc/logstash/jvm.options

The recommended heap size for typical ingestion scenarios should be no less than 4GB and no more than 8GB.

CPU utilization can increase unnecessarily if the heap size is too low, resulting in the JVM constantly garbage collecting. You can check for this issue by doubling the heap size to see if performance improves.
Do not increase the heap size past the amount of physical memory. Some memory must be left to run the OS and other processes. As a general guideline for most installations, don’t exceed 50-75% of physical memory. The more memory you have, the higher percentage you can use.

Set the minimum (Xms) and maximum (Xmx) heap allocation size to the same value to prevent the heap from resizing at runtime, which is a very costly process.

You can make more accurate measurements of the JVM heap by using either the jmap command line utility distributed with Java or by using VisualVM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @hagay_bar! Your answer could be improved by providing more specifics about your instruction.

Comment: done. hope it will cover it all

Comment: Thanks, @hagay_bar! Giving you a "useful" vote for your good answer.